# How to show all messages with any label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I want to see a list of all mail that has **any** label, including the inbox label. This is similar to the `All Mail` view, except All Mail also shows archived messages. I don't want to see the archived messages (there are [over 9000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik))... just messages with a label.

If you search Google, it will consistently misinterpret the query no matter how you phrase it and pollute the results with plenty of posts about how to present messages with no label. This would be the "All Mail" view, and is not helpful to me.

How can I do this?

Comment: " don't want to see the archived messages (there are over 9000)... just messages with a label." Archived messages are messages without the inbox label. I am confused by what group of messages you are looking for. An archived message can have zero, one, or more labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail has user created labels and system labels. `inbox` is one of the system labels.

To search for email with

- user created labels use: `has:userlabels`
- user created labels *or* inbox label use: `has:userlabels | in:inbox`

Resource

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: The `has:userlabels | in:inbox` is exactly what I need, thanks!